Integrating Causeway in Spring Boot 3.2.6 with Postgresql: An exception occurred while calling convertToEntityAttribute
We have an existing REST API project in Spring Boot 3.2.6, Java 21, with JPA entities and Spring Data. The database is Postgresql 16.2.
The goal was to integrate Causeway in there to manage some "admin" entities with it.
I did that by adding the following Causeway dependencies (no idea if they are all required):
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.mavendeps</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-mavendeps-webapp</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency> 
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.viewer</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-viewer-wicket-viewer</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.viewer</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-viewer-restfulobjects-jaxrsresteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-security-shiro</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-persistence-jpa-eclipselink</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.viewer</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-viewer-wicket-applib</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-testing-h2console-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        </dependency>
            
            
        <!-- Causeway security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-security-keycloak</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.causeway.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>causeway-security-bypass</artifactId>
        </dependency>

The Keycloak part is needed as we are using Keycloak and it does work perfectly with Causeway.
After doing that, my understanding is that the Hibernate implementation of JPA was replaced with an EclipseLink implementation. I had to make some slight adjustments in my Entities and the project was launching correctly.
Our controllers are hit correctly when making requests, but EclipseLink is throwing exceptions for entities using UUID properties:
An exception occurred while calling convertToEntityAttribute on converter class org.apache.causeway.persistence.jpa.integration.typeconverters.java.util.JavaUtilUuidConverter with value 43047078-e2ba-4e34-8fdd-1b33df84f816

The same thing happens with OffsetDateTime properties.
My questions are:

Can I switch back to the Hibernate implementation ?
If not, how can I get rid of those exceptions ?

Thanks!


Can I switch back to the Hibernate implementation ?
No, not at the moment.  Causeway only supports EclipseLink because of licensing restrictions with Hibernate (LGPL is not compatible with Apache Software License v2, at least according to ASF).
We recently learnt that Hibernate is in fact going to move to ASLv2 also, but no timescales have been released.  We will therefore be providing a Hibernate integration in due course, but can't give any dates ... it won't be this year, that is for sure.

If not, how can I get rid of those exceptions ?
It's a bit hard to say without seeing those exceptions!  What I would suggest is that you fork our simpleapp starter app and use that to demonstrate the issue.  Then, join our slack and we can assist you from there.



Thanks for the answer, I'll try to find some time to build a minimal application replicating those issues so you can see the exceptions in detail.
